# Regular expression to find phrases within markers

Tags: python, regex

I need a regular expression for `re.findall` that returns anything between '$' signs:

```
Sentence = "The person, $John Doe$, works at $Lan Tech$ as a $Sales Engineer$."
```

Printing should produce =

```
['John Doe', 'Lan Tech', 'Sales Engineer']
```

Note: I could use something else other than '$' if it would be easier.

Comment: Oh do you? We need things too... What have you tried?

Comment: Tried this re.findall(r'\$+\w\$', Sentence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.findall()` with a capturing group:

```
re.findall(r'\$([^$]*)\$', Sentence)
```

Example:

```
>>> Sentence = "The person, $John Doe$, works at $Lan Tech$ as a $Sales Engineer$."
>>> re.findall(r'\$([^$]*)\$', Sentence)
['John Doe', 'Lan Tech', 'Sales Engineer']
```

Explanation: You need to escape each `$` in the regex, because an unescaped `$` acts as an end of string anchor in regex.  The group is everything inside of the parentheses, and `re.findall()` will only return the contents of groups if you have any, which is why the `$`s are not included in the resulting list.  Inside of the group, `[^$]*` will match any number of characters that are not `$`.